# Poll: A little survey about user intents

Tags: discussion, user-poll

The purpose of this post is to better gauge what PuzzlingSE means to various people, and hence help to better adjust rules and guidelines in the future.$^*$

> - ### Please up-vote only a single of the answers given below.
> - Do not down-vote.
> - Feel free to add coments
> - If you feel some *fundamental* option is missing, add it as comunity-wiki $^{**}$

<sub>* To some extent, it also just serves the purpose of satisfying my own curisosity.</sub>

<sub>** Keeping the list of answer options minimal is important. Only add if it is really needed. Otherwise, use comments to explain yourself.</sub>

Comment: I (primarily) came here to conquer the world, dominate the galaxies and rule the universe!

Comment: I (primarily) came here to see how the community is going on right now. I don't even look at the puzzles, only the management side.

Comment: @manshu, interesting! Why, if I may ask?

Comment: It's because in times like these, a community gets interesting-er. And last time I checked there had been so many low quality questions (in my opinion) asked on this site that were not only accepted by this community but could also be seen on the Hot Network Questions. That thing disappointed me. I might re-look at the main site though in few days.

Comment: @manshu It is the struggle between restriction and allowing "creativity" which has been a problem here all along, and while various attempts have been made to improve, it still is a huge challenge. I agree, that a lot of stuff is not *really* helpful on this site, but being too restrictive is also bad and close-impossible anyway. The main problem is, that some StackExchange-given methods (like HNQ and voting-reputation) are based on different site mechanics and totally [fail for Puzzling](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/can-we-have-site-specific-control-over-hnq).

Comment: I (primarily) came here from a hot network question and found this community awesome :)

Answer (score 11):

## Posting puzzles? Solving puzzles?  I *really* do both with equal measures and have no preference to either

Comment: I upvoted this one because it most closely corresponds with the actual reason I come here, but learning about how other people solve and build puzzles is a huge part of it too. (Also, I'll (slightly shamefully) admit that watching my rep go up is rewarding. :P )

Answer (score 10):

## I (primarily) come to this site for just simple curiosity and fun. Just occasionally I will post a question or answer.

Comment: I enjoy both posting and solving puzzles, but I would say my primary purpose is just to consume and enjoy the site content.

Comment: I enjoy both also, and would do them more often if I had the time, but I think that, at least right now, I am coming to the site as just an interested onlooker.

Comment: Most of the time, I'm way too slow at puzzle-solving to compete with you all :P I like seeing how people have solved elaborate puzzles or things like ciphers (which I'm especially useless at), and trying to make my own, but mostly I just watch and upvote.

Answer (score 7):

## I (primarily) come to this site to solve puzzles

I come to this site because.... <sub>(Add comment)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## I (primarily) come to this site to post my own puzzles

I do this because.... <sub>(Add comment)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## I (primarily) come to this site when researching a particular puzzle or puzzle-building aspect

I use the site as a knowledge-base, just like other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

## I (primarily) come to this site to compete with others on solving puzzles

Solving puzzles is fun for me, but the real challenge is to be faster/better than others...

Answer (score 0):

## I (primarily) come to this site to learn how others solve or build puzzles

I usually don't particpate acitvely in posting questions, answers or comments.